# Graphviz dot - Italic text in HTML table is non-italic

Tags: svg, graphviz, dot, italic

I'm using `dot` version 2.26.3

The following `.dot` contents:

```
digraph html {
results [shape=none, margin=0, label=<
    <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="4">
    <TR>
    <TD>Title</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD><I>Description.</I></TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>
>];
}
```

..should produce a non-italic 'Title' and italic 'Description' when generating an SVG according to [the documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html).

`dot -Tsvg filename.dot -o output/filename.svg`

However, the description is non-italic as you can see:

[image]

Any idea why?

### UPDATE

I couldn't get the latest version installed for various reasons.
In the end I remedied by using an italicised font.
Equally, you could use a strong font as an equivalent for bold.

`<TD><FONT FACE="Times-Roman">Standard.</FONT></TD>`

`<TD><FONT FACE="Times-Italic">In italics.</FONT></TD>`

`<TD><FONT FACE="Times-Bold">In bold.</FONT></TD>`

Comment: Do you mean "bold" instead of "italic"? PNG output for `<B>` is bold: http://i.imgur.com/IvOGj.png I would expect `<I>` to be used for italics (not that it would fix your problem to use `<I>`, I'm just confused why you're asking about italics).

Comment: Whoops, thanks for that tenterhook. When `<I>` failed I tried `<B>` which also didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's why - from the link to the documentation you provided:

> The font markups for bold, italic, underlining, subscript and
>   superscript (`<B>`, `<I>`, `<U>`, `<SUB>`; and `<SUP`>) are only available in
>   versions **after 14 October 2011**, and are currently only available via
>   the cairo and svg renderers

Version 2.26.3 however seems to be from **January 2010** - at least when checking the dates of the [downloads for ubuntu](http://www.graphviz.org/pub/graphviz/stable/ubuntu/ub9.04/x86_64/) or [windows](http://www.graphviz.org/pub/graphviz/stable/windows/).

I recommend to upgrade.

Comment: The most recently modified versions according to those directories are also before 14 October 2011. :S

Comment: Sincere thanks, marapet. I saw that comment and foolishly presumed the latest version in Ubuntu repositories was a post-Oct 2011 release.

Answer (score 1):

I have version `2.28` installed, and my local documentation (`C:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.28\share\graphviz\doc\html\info\shapes.html#html`) makes no mention of *any* `<I>` or `<B>` tags under the `HTML-Like Labels` section. It appears that the tags still work when producing `png` output, but the support was (apparently) either removed from or never added to the `svg` functionality and is now (apparently) not supported for any output.

Comment: Thank you for the info, tenterhook.

Comment: You're right, this is not in the documentation packaged with 2.28 (and 2.29 dev). Strangely, those are the versions it works - though I wouldn't bet my money on this being available in future versions. I couldn't find anything about this being deprecated. However, svg output does include a `font-style="italic"` attribute - at least on my windows box.

Comment: @marapet Which version produces the `font-style="italic"` output for you? 2.28 just turns `...<TD><I>Description.</I></TD>...` into `... <text text-anchor="start" x="5.5" y="-8.8" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="14.00">Description.</text> ... ` in the svg output for me.

Comment: Both 2.28 and 2.29.20110921, on windows.